# C# - Options to return multiple error types from method

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I currently have to following method written in .NET Standard 2.0

```
/// <summary>
/// Get all items
/// </summary>
/// <returns>All Items</returns>
/// <exception cref="Exception"></exception>
public List<Item> GetAllItems()
```

The items are from an external source which I have no control over. The method throws an exception if:

- The external source can't be reached
- There are invalid items

It turns out, that throwing an exception if there are invalid items is not working for us. We always want all valid items, but I also want to communicate that there are items missing.

My first thought on how to fix it was a method like

```
public bool TryGetAllItems(out List<Item> result)
```

But this doesn't work, since I don't want to return neither false nor true if there are valid and invalid items. Next idea was something like

```
public List<Item> GetAllItems(out string errorMessage)
```

But also this option is not really satisfying since it is hard to differentiate between different errors (e.g. no connection or invalid items), parsing the error seems too dirty.

My last thougt was the following

```
public ErrorCode GetAllItems(out List<Item> result, out string errorMessage)
```

What do you think, is there a better option that I missed?

In the end I always want a valid result (i.e. at least an empty list) with different type of errors. I am using .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [OneOf library](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf).

Then you could do:

```cs
public bool TryGetAllItems(out List<Item> result, out OneOf<NoConnection,InvalidItems> error)
```